# Graph database with hierarchical domain?

Tags: database, graph, hierarchical-data

Can I have a graph database and still load it into a hierarchical domain-model? Why? I want both the benefits of a graph database and the structure of a hierarchical domain where nodes can be descendants and ancestors.

Comment: Some graph databases, like Neo4j, allow for directed edges/relationships. These are like one-way relationships. You can easily use directed edges to create a hierarchy.